Add attributes to target info metric only?
How do I add attributes to the target info metric without adding them to spans?
This code will add attributes to both the target info metric and all the spans:
AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk.builder
  .addResourceCustomizer((resource, _) =>
    resource.merge(Resource.create(Attributes.of(
      AttributeKey.stringKey("version.workflow"), classOf[Workflow].getPackage.getImplementationVersion,
      AttributeKey.stringKey("version.stream"), classOf[Stream].getPackage.getImplementationVersion,
      AttributeKey.stringKey("version.kafka"), org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser.getVersion,
    ))
  )
)
  .build()

How do I add these attributes to just the target info metric and to spans?

Use addMeterProviderCustomizer instead of addResourceCustomizer.
Like so:
AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk.builder
  .addMeterProviderCustomizer((meterProviderBuilder, _) =>
    meterProviderBuilder.addResource(Resource.create(Attributes.of(
      AttributeKey.stringKey("version.workflow"), classOf[Workflow].getPackage.getImplementationVersion,
      AttributeKey.stringKey("version.stream"), classOf[Stream].getPackage.getImplementationVersion,
      AttributeKey.stringKey("version.kafka"), org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser.getVersion,
    ))
  )
)
  .build()

